# Json to dataframe (empty observations, different lengths)

Tags: r, json, dataframe

Through an API I accessed weather information in Json format. I want to convert this data to a dataframe. The problem is that not for every date-city combination the api returns weather conditions, so a few rows are empty. Second , not every combination that does return gives the same aspects of the weather. My goal is to convert the Json to a dataframe, where rows that are empty are still showed in the dataframe (which does not happen when I unlist them)  and the different aspects of the weather are properly showed under the right variable  with NA values if there is no record for that particular variable. I've tried enlisting them and putting it into a dataframe, flattening the table etc (getting the error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1) . I've searched for this topic but none of them worked for my case  (or maybe because I'm not that experienced I applied them wrong), but every tip is welcome!

The input looks like this:

```
reviewid    dateofwriting   lon         lat
98338143    28-02-11        11,41693611 22,3193039
58929813    18-03-10        -3,7037902  40,4167754
65945346    31-05-10        -3,188267   55,953252
```

The output looks like this (the second observation returns 36 columns and the third one 38. the first entry is missing because there was no observation for that day and is not displayed)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1MbD.png)

```
    [{},
    {"daily":
       [{"time":"2010-03-18",
       "summary":"Partly cloudy throughout the day.",
       "icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
       "sunriseTime":"2010-03-18 07:22:51",
       "sunsetTime":"2010-03-18 19:25:28",
       "moonPhase":0.08,
       "precipIntensity":0,
       "precipIntensityMax":0,
       "precipProbability":0,
       "temperatureHigh":63.14,  
       "temperatureHighTime":1268928000,
       "temperatureLow":45.16,
       "temperatureLowTime":1268971200,
       "apparentTemperatureHigh":63.14,
       "apparentTemperatureHighTime":1268928000,
       "apparentTemperatureLow":45.16,
       "apparentTemperatureLowTime":1268971200,
       "dewPoint":36.97,
       "humidity":0.58,
       "pressure":1025.96,
       "windSpeed":1.24,
       "windGust":7.87, 
       "windGustTime":1268866800,
       "windBearing":48,
       "cloudCover":0.54,
       "uvIndex":5,
       "uvIndexTime":1268913600,
       "visibility":6.19,
       "temperatureMin":43.97,
       "temperatureMinTime":"2010-03-18 07:00:00",
       "temperatureMax":63.14,
       "temperatureMaxTime":"2010-03-18 17:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMin":42.03,
       "apparentTemperatureMinTime":"2010-03-18 08:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMax":63.14,
       "apparentTemperatureMaxTime":"2010-03-18 17:00:00"}]},

    {"daily":
       [{"time":"2010-05-30 01:00:00",
       "summary":"Mostly cloudy until evening.",
       "icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
       "sunriseTime":"2010-05-30 05:38:39",
       "sunsetTime":"2010-05-30 22:44:55",
       "moonPhase":0.58,
       "precipIntensity":0.0038,
       "precipIntensityMax":0.0766,
       "precipIntensityMaxTime”:"2010-05-30 04:00:00",
       "precipProbability":1,
       "precipType":"rain", 
       "temperatureHigh":58.99,
       "temperatureHighTime":1275242400, 
       "temperatureLow":36.62,  
       "temperatureLowTime":1275278400, 
       "apparentTemperatureHigh":58.99, 
       "apparentTemperatureHighTime":1275242400, 
       "apparentTemperatureLow":36.62,
       "apparentTemperatureLowTime":1275278400,
       "dewPoint":43.61,
       "humidity":0.76,
       "pressure":1011.52,
       "windSpeed":4.65,
       "windGust":21.4,
       "windGustTime":1275224400,
       "windBearing":350,
       "cloudCover":0.61,
       "uvIndex":5,
       "uvIndexTime":1275213600,
       "visibility":5.85, 
       "temperatureMin":45.99,
       "temperatureMinTime":"2010-05-30 07:00:00",
       "temperatureMax":58.99,
       "temperatureMaxTime":"2010-05-30 20:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMin":43.31,
       "apparentTemperatureMinTime":"2010-05-30 06:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMax":58.99,
       "apparentTemperatureMaxTime":"2010-05-30 20:00:00"}]}]
```

The goal is to add these rows to the input excel above.

```
icon                sunrisetime     sunsettime      etc.
NA                  NA              NA              etc.
partly-cloudy-day   18-03-10 07:22  18-03-10 19:25  etc.
partly-cloudy-day   30-05-10 05:38  30-05-10 22:44  etc.
```

Comment: iám assuming the JSON is valid as the message isn't posted complete.. Maybe it helps to deploy a SQL capable server which has JSON support to convert the JSON message into records/columns more easy..  But it might be a long workaround as i do not know if you need to save the results..

Comment: More or less like this in MySQL 8 see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/68UWRxPMj3Co4gUEe7aJae/2) it should save you some programming in R i geuss

Comment: @raymond Ah I never used that before, but from your demo it looks very convenient! Will definitely give it a shot if it doesn't work through R (in a bit of a thesis time constraint, so working with a new program looks more time-consuming for now), but thank you!

Comment: well good luck as i can't really help you in R as i never worked with it before i would most likely figure out working code on how to connect to MySQL and query it if i would study the manual, MySQL on the other hand is a different story and yes using MySQL makes it very convenient and easy.. *"in a bit of a thesis time constraint, so working with a new program looks more time-consuming for now"* As you are storing/working and manipulate data alot when programming it would make some sense for you to learn SQL in the future i geuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem dealing with the responses that return NULL.  To simplify the issue, it is easier to remove these non responses and then parse the remaining JSON response. If desired, one can go back and add the empty rows for the non responses.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

#test<- result from converting the JSON response.  
#vector of reviewid, used to make the initial request to the API
reviewid<-c(98338143, 58929813, 65945346)

#find only the responses that are not Null or blank
valid<-which(sapply(1:nrow(test),  function(j) {length(test[[1]][[j]])}) >0)
NullResponses<-which(sapply(1:nrow(test),  function(j) {length(test[[1]][[j]])}) == 0)

#create a list of data frames with the data from row of the response
dflist<-lapply( valid, function(j) {
  temp<-t(as.matrix(unlist(test[j,])))
  df<-data.frame(reviewid=reviewid[j], temp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df
  })
#bind the rows together.
answer<-bind_rows(dflist)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, you are my hero! It seems like this should do the job. I have one question, when I run valid and NullResponses I keep getting the error: 'Error in 1:nrow(test) : argument of length 0' and I don't know how to get rid of it. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @EvelienvanderWaal, it may be possible you don't have any Null blank responses thus the error.  You could try this instead: `which(!(1:nrow(test) %in% valid))`

Comment: Ah I tried that, but unfortunately this gives the same error.

Comment: @EvelienvanderWaal, I can only guess is all of your is complete and there are no empty sets thus the `which` function is returning an empty set.  This line is really not needed so I would comment it out or move to the end of the code block.

Comment: It gives this error for the valid responses as well so it probably is because of something else, but thank you for your time! I will ask someone else.

Comment: mystery solved, so thanks again, been stuck on this for ages